# How can I tell if my computer has started the Windows 10 upgrade?

Tags: windows-update, windows-10-upgrade

I've reserved the Windows 10 upgrade on my tablet PC (running Win 7). Yesterday Microsoft has started distributing it — though not to everyone at once — saying users will be notified when it's available on their computer "in the coming days or weeks".

I'm not in a hurry, but I'd like to know **how I can tell when it's my turn**. What are the cues that tell me my computer has started downloading it?
(Other than monitoring network traffic, I mean. Perhaps some file or folder that's created, or some entry in some kind of update log?)

I've already tried running `wuauclt.exe/updatenow` in an Administrator command prompt to force the upgrade, as suggested elsewhere on the internet, but I've seen no signs that any kind of update process has started.

Comment: There isn't a method to determine when it will be your turn.  You can just tell when you have started by the existence of those folders in Jooshua's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Click the Windows 10 icon in notification area (the one that was previously used to place a reservation). The window that will open will contain information on progress.

Comment: What if we don't have it anymore?

Comment: @James_Parsons - Then your system is not preparing the download.  The upgrade is a phase roll out, confirmed by Microsoft, the "get windows 10" application did one thing indicate you wanted to do that.  The procedure itself will go through Windows Update.  The icon is disappearing for a reason, I suspect, it was either hidden on purpose or the application is silently crashing because of a scripting error on the content attempting displaying.  I was able to just use the .ISO but the icon did disappear on me yesterday.

Comment: @James_Parsons Refer to Joshua Haber's answer.

Comment: ...however, @MC10, if the icon is not there anymore, it might never start any downloading?

Comment: I don't think the icon is the most essential part of the upgrade process...I doubt it controls the whole thing.

Comment: @Arjan - It is after July 29th you can reserve your copy through Windows Update.

Comment: @Ramhound actually, I had to do a factory reset.

Comment: Looks like it's as simple as that! The update has only just started on my end, so I couldn't confirm it until now.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `C:\$Windows.~BT` and `C:\$Windows.~WS` folders it should have started downloading. (both are hidden by default)

Comment: This is also true - those folders appeard a couple of minutes after the "Windows 10 icon" window informed me the download had started.